# ArcGIS Editor Toolbar

Tags: arcgis-9.3, tools, editing

Does anyone know how to change the properties of a vertex to keep 3 places after the decimal place? My problem is when I go to draw a line and snap to a point, the properties of the line I am drawing are rounding to the nearest whole number instead of keeping the correct number of decimal places and the vertex positions arent staying where I need them to stay. Is there some way to fix this in some kind of settings or options menu. In the Editor Menu - Options, I have Display measurements using 3 decimal places but when I start drawing a line, it rounds to a whole number for each vertex so every vertex is just a little off of where it needs to be.

Comment: what is your data source? mdb, shape? What is your coord sys? you can edit your question with more info and clarification

Answer (score 1):

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Geodatabase_field_data_types

Create a new geodatabase or shapefile with scale and precision set and import your current data into the new file.

0 to 1,234.56789  Data type=Double  Precision=9     Scale=5